# How to solve $x<\frac{1}{x+2}$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, inequality

Need some help with:

$$x<\frac{1}{x+2}$$

This is what I have done:

$$Domain: x\neq-2$$

$$x(x+2)<1$$
$$x^2+2x-1<0$$
$$x_{1,2} = \frac{-2\pm\sqrt{4+4}}{2} = \frac{2 \pm \sqrt{8}}{2} = \frac{-2\pm2\sqrt{2}}{2}$$

What about now?

Comment: What if $x=-2$ ?

Comment: When you multiply with (x+2) you have to seperate two cases, since x+2 can be negativ. In that case the relationssymbol < changes its "direction". Also $x\neq -2$

Comment: edited, was a typo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Multiply the inequality by $\;(x+2)^2>0\;$ ( obviously, $\;x\neq-2\;$) :

$$x(x+2)^2<x+2\iff x^3+4x^2+3x-2<0\iff$$

$$\iff (x+2)(x+1-\sqrt2)(x+1+\sqrt2)<0\iff \color{red}{x<-1-\sqrt 2}\;\;\text{or}\;\color{red}{-2<x<-1+\sqrt2}$$

Comment: why $(x+2)^2$ in both side?

Comment: @Taponiza That way you (1) get rid of the denominator, and (2) you don't have to check two different inequalities because of the sign: something squared is **always** non-negative, or as  in this case, positive.

Comment: the way you factor the cubique equation might be tricky for OP... I would not develop it and go from $x(x+2)^2<(x+2) \iff (x+2)(x(x+2)-1)<0$ then there is no need to deal with cubique equations (directly).

Comment: @Surb Thank you. True, yet in many cases of exercises like this one there is at least one rational root, as in this case with $\;x=-2\;$ , so we can always divide and calculate a quadratic equation's roots. Yet your idea for this *particular* case is very nice, indeed.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint 1:** You already did a mistake: When you multiply by $(x+2)$ the inequality changes if $x+2<0$.

So first split the problem in two cases: $x+2 >0$ and $x+2<0$.

**Hint 2** Factor $x^2+2x-1=(x-x_1)(x-x_2)$ and disscuss the sign of each linear term.

Answer (score 1):

The inequation is equivalent to

$$x-\frac1{x+2}=\frac{x^2+2x-1}{x+2}=\frac{(x-(-1-\sqrt2))(x-(-1+\sqrt2))}{x-(-2)}<0.$$

For the expression to be negative, you need an odd number of negative factors.

$$\begin{array}{l|ccccccc}
&&-1-\sqrt2&&-2&&-1+\sqrt2\\
\hline x-(-1-\sqrt2)&\color{green}-&0&+&+&\color{green}+&+&+\\
x-(-2)&\color{green}-&-&-&0&\color{green}+&+&+\\
x-(-1+\sqrt2)&\color{green}-&-&-&-&\color{green}-&0&+\\
\hline
&\color{green}-&0&+&|&\color{green}-&0&+\\
\end{array}$$

Comment: @N.F.Taussig Busy fixing...